# Referencing a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, graph, reference

First of all, please know that I have done extensive research on a solution to my problem, but none of the solutions appear to work. I'm trying to create a graph. Long story short, I can't seem to add edges to any of my nodes because the function that does so:

```
void pushEdge(node * dest, int weight) {
    edges.push_back(edge(this,dest,weight));
}
```

doesn't reference the actual "edges" vector. When I print out the edges, nothing prints out because every node apparently has no edges despite the fact that I added them earlier.

**How can I reference a class vector inside a class function?**

Code: (Run this if you want to, you'll see that there are 0 edges.

graph.h - Stores the edge, node, and graph classes.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class node;

class edge {
public:
    edge(){}
    edge(node * origin, node * dest, int weight) {
        this->origin = origin;
        this->dest = dest;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
    node * origin;
    node * dest;
    int weight;

 };

class node {
public:
node(){}
node(int x, int y, int t) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->t = t;
}

vector<edge> edges;
int x; int t; int y;

void pushEdge(node * dest, int weight) {
    edges.push_back(edge(this,dest,weight));
}

void printEdges() {
    cout << "NODE (" << this->x << "," << this->y << "): " << edges.size() << " edges!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        edge at = edges.at(i);
        cout << "EDGE: Origin(" << at.origin->x << "," << at.origin->y << ") Target(" << at.dest->x << "," << at.dest->y << ") Weight: " << at.weight << endl;
    }
}
};

class graph {
public:
graph(){}
node nodes[900] = {};

void printNodes() {
    cout << "Node count: " << sizeof(this->nodes) << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
        this->nodes[i].printEdges();
    }
}
};
```

source.cpp - Generates a graph and prints it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph.h"

using namespace std;

graph genGraph();

int main() {
graph myGraph = genGraph();
myGraph.printNodes();
}

graph genGraph() {
graph myGraph;
int i = 0;
for (int x = 1; x <= 30; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y <= 30; y++) {
        node myNode(x, y, 0);
        myGraph.nodes[i] = myNode;
        i += 1;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
    node myNode = myGraph.nodes[i];
    int x = myNode.x; int y = myNode.y;
    if (x > 1) {
        node nodeLeft = myGraph.nodes[i-30];
        myNode.pushEdge(&nodeLeft, 2);
        if (y > 1) {
            node nodeTopLeft = myGraph.nodes[i-31];
            myNode.pushEdge(&nodeTopLeft, 2);
        }
        if (y < 30) {
            node nodeBottomLeft = myGraph.nodes[i-29];
            myNode.pushEdge(&nodeBottomLeft, 2);
            cout << myNode.edges.size() << endl;
        }
    }
    if (x < 30) {
        node nodeRight = myGraph.nodes[i+30];
        myNode.pushEdge(&nodeRight, 2);
        if (y > 1) {
            node nodeTopRight = myGraph.nodes[i+29];
            myNode.pushEdge(&nodeTopRight, 2);
        }
        if (y < 30) {
            node nodeBottomRight = myGraph.nodes[i + 31];
            myNode.pushEdge(&nodeBottomRight, 2);
        }
    }
    if (y > 1) {
        node nodeTop = myGraph.nodes[i - 1];
        myNode.pushEdge(&nodeTop, 2);
    }
    if (y < 30) {
        node nodeBottom = myGraph.nodes[i + 1];
        myNode.pushEdge(&nodeBottom, 2);
    }
}
return myGraph;
}
```

Thanks,
Max K

Comment: How about trying the Boost Graph library?

Comment: Have you tried to read a textbook?

Comment: @Slava I understand the concept of a graph well enough. My problem is referencing a vector.

Comment: A global vector with pointers to quite transient objects, is not a good idea.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ignore the quality of the code. I rewrote a section of  the actual code to highlight the issue that I am facing.

Comment: @MaxK I did not mean a textbook about graph, I mean C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is with

```
node myNode = myGraph.nodes[i];
```

as you there create a copy of node i. You can create a reference:

```
node& myNode = myGraph.nodes[i];
```

Comment: Yes, that solved it! I can't believe I didn't realize that the problem was referencing the nodes.

Comment: Now if I run it though, the ending edges have coordinate values of -858993460. Thoughts?

Comment: @MaxK `for (int i = 0; i < 900; i++)` iterates 900 `node`s. You only made 30. What's in the other 870 `node`s? No one knows because the `node` default constructor (`node(){}`) doesn't do anything. Could be random garbage, could be a secret code that unlocks the gates of Hell, could be the complete works of William Shakespeare translated into Swahili. Consider using `vector` and `push_back` instead of the 900 element array.

Comment: @user4581301 look at those double for loops again. 30x30 = 900. And yes, a vector was in my original code, but I changed it to a raw array because there are 900 nodes every time guaranteed, so an array seems for sensible in terms of storage.

Comment: @MaxK You've got me there. Only think left that I can think of is you haven't carried Johan Lundberg's advice all the way through and are still printing pointers to out of scope locals. eg. exact same mistake here: `node nodeLeft = myGraph.nodes[i-30];` and a dozen more times through the code.